# Selecting specific range instead of active range in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script on Google App Script that will, at one point, get a range from one sheet, copy the values on that range and paste them to another sheet.

I have done so by doing this:

```
    var range = sh.getDataRange().offset(0, 0);  
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME')
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)
```

I would like, however, to specify the exact range to copy and another exact range to paste the data into.

I would like the range to be copied/pasted to be from columns A to Z whilst still keeping the `getLastRow()` in the script.

How would I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By specifying those bounds when acquiring the respective `Range` variable. Try it first, read documentation for help and the required research, and include the code you come up with in your question. Hint: You'll use the numeric equivalent of `col A` and `col Z`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) to fetch a range and its contents. I usually go for A1 notation. Sample:

```
// Get a range A1:D4 on sheet titled "Invoices"
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getRange("Invoices!A1:D4");
 // Get cell A1 on the first sheet
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
```

There are other variations of getRange you can use. Choose what you're comfortable with.

For copying and pasting altogether, you can use the [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

```
  // The code below copies the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```